# A new nation joined the Olympic Games

Tags: riddle

> A new nation joined the Olympic Games.
>
> One of their athletes won the gold at every race event
>
> While another won the hearts of the spectators
>
> One tried shooting but ended up hitting most of his teammates
>
> Still, the most hurt of them performed well in wrestling
>
> One excelled at all team sports
>
> While his father thrived in gymnastics and natation
>
> But one was made fun of for unmentionable reasons
>
> And another showed up late after being announced
>
> Sadly, one was forced to abandon
>
> Which nation is it ?

Comment: ...but everything changed when the fire nation attacked.

Comment: "One tried shooting but ended up hitting most of his teammates" and this isn't America?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems very correct. Hope the *reasons*  I gave are correct too.

---

These are

> The nine planets (Or rather, the 8 planets and one dwarf planet)!

One of their athletes won the gold at every race event

> **Mercury** goes around the sun the fastest.

While another won the hearts of the spectators

> **Venus** is the goddess of beauty and love.

One tried shooting but ended up hitting most of his teammates

> **Earth** has sent many probes to other planets (thanks @Gareth!).

Still, the most hurt of them performed well in wrestling

> We have sent the most number of probes to **Mars** and he is the god of war (thank you @A.B.!).

One excelled at all team sports

> **Jupiter** has the most moons, I suppose.

While his father thrived in gymnastics and natation

> **Saturn** has rings and is less dense than water. Also, in Roman mythology, Saturn is Jupiter’s father.

But one was made fun of for unmentionable reasons

> **Uranus** sounds like 'Your Anus'.

And another showed up late after being announced

> **Neptune** was proved to exist mathematically before it was actually discovered (thanks again @Gareth!).

Sadly, one was forced to abandon

> **Pluto** is not a planet anymore.

Comment: Well, that was quick... The explanations are complete except for the 3rd, 4th and 8th ones, any more ideas ?

Comment: 3rd is probably because we have sent probes to several other planets. 8th perhaps because Neptune's position was predicted mathematically before it was actually observed.

Comment: My presumptions for 3rd: Shooting rockets and satellites and not 'hitting' or 'landing' on anything but other 'teammates'. For the 8th: It was first mentioned from mathematical deduction before it was observed

Comment: Only thing I can think of for #4 is that it is the planet that we have most attempted to discover and research, sending the most spacecrafts and satellites to it out of the rest, and, also, god of war

Comment: @A.B. & Gareth, these are the correct explanations, good job !

Comment: Pluto is already a planet again.